# showing that $h$ and $G_v$ generate $Aut(G)$.

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected 
vertex-transitive graph and let $G_v$ denote the stabilizer of the vertex 
$v$. If $h$ is any automorphism of $G$ for which $d(v,h(v)) = 1$, and $G$ is 
symmetric, then $h$ and $G_v$ generate $Aut(G)$.

my Idea is to take an arbitrary member of $Aut(G)$ and show that it is equal to combination of members of $G_v$ and $h$,(of course it is the natural way)but I don't know how should I use the hypothesis to achieve,

any help or guidance will be great.

Comment: 1.) Is $d$ distance in graph $G$? 2.) What does '$G$ is symmetric' mean? We already know that $G$ is vertex-transitive. Is it also edge-transitive (arc-transitive), or what word 'symmetric' stands for?

Comment: @ Stefan Gyürki,it means that both vertex-transitive and edge transitive,in question symmetric was enough but it repeated about vertex transitive.and yes $d$ means shortest path between two vertex.